# Access Download folder on Android 10

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

I have a working code that exports some files in the Downloads folder. I'm using `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to be able to access the folder on Android 10-. Everything works.

Since Google Play Store requested to remove the flag

> requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

I have tried to remove it. I don't need to migrate anything so it has been relatively simple and it works fine on Android 9- and Android 11. On Android 10 it does not work. The app crashes with

> android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

In the AndroidManifest I have:

```
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

I have granted permission to access the external store.

The crash happens when I call:

```
destination.outputStream()
```

where `destination` is a file in the `Downloads` folder.

What should I do? Why doesn't this work on Android 10 only?

Comment: `The app crashes` Dont let your app crash but catch that exeption. Also use File.canRead() and such. And show full reproducable code as we have no idea what you do.

Comment: Thank you. The app crashes all the times. To hide the crash catching the exception is not a solution and checking whether the file is readable is not a solution either. I have published the relevant code. There is much more but the  `destination.outputStream()` is the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: The solution is to leave that flag in manifest. Did you try to upload it with flag and was it refused because of that?

Comment: This question is mainly about whether there is a way to access the `Downloads` folder without using that flag, in Android 10 and if not, why is this issue only on Android 10

Answer (score 1):

The issue on Android 10, because you set in In the AndroidManifest : android:maxSdkVersion="29".

Android 10 is API level 29.

add in AndroidMainfest

in application node

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```